# How can I detect outer Html tag of key in Html?

Tags: android, html, jsoup, retrofit

I fetch the HTML page source with retrofit and save it in String. And i am searching for a key(Product Price) in this String.I can find the key in the String and how can I find the outer html tag or class that containing the key ?

```
<input name="productPrice" id="productPrice" value="74.90"
               type="hidden"/>
```

Simply in this HTML tag, I can find `74.90.` And how can I find the id or name?

```
<div class="newPrice">
    <ins content="3099.00">3.099,00 <span content="TRY">TL</span> 
    </ins><span class="kdv">KDV <br>DAHİL</span>
</div>
```

And this is another example. I can find 3099.00. And how can I find the div's class name?

I hope I can explain the problem

Comment: Can you please elaborate WHAT exactly you did to find the price in the first place?

Comment: I just use indexOf() function

Comment: jsoup has excellent document access methods, e.g. you can turn the HTML text into a document object and then use something like `document.getElementById("productPrice")` to get hold of the element etc.

Comment: @devnull69 I just know the price and want to know the id. I have different html pages. And every page has different id and tags.

Answer (score 0):

To get the class, select what you know - element `ins` with attribute `content` having value `3099.00`. Then select its parent and get the class of this parent.

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class JsoupIssue57005455 {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {

        String html = "<div class=\"newPrice\">"
                + "    <ins content=\"3099.00\">3.099,00 <span content=\"TRY\">TL</span> "
                + "    </ins><span class=\"kdv\">KDV <br>DAHİL</span>" 
                + "</div>";
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

        System.out.println(doc.select("ins[content=3099.00]").first().parent().className());
    }
}
```

output: `newPrice`